# Merging Excel worksheets into one

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do you merge multiple Excel worksheets into one without losing/overwriting data? I have been given the task of taking the daily logs at my workplace and combining them into a monthly log. Each daily sheet is in its own file. Is there an easier (and quicker!) way other than copy/paste each sheet? I want to say I saw a method for this ages ago, but for the life of me cannot remember how to do so now! We use Excel 2003 in case that makes any difference!

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with VB macros, you can try the script [found here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=773). I have used this script for many years now, and is now part of my Excel cheatsheet warchest must-haves.

Verified to work on Excel 2003.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:

http://video.about.com/spreadsheets/Merge-Spreadsheets-in-Excel.htm

Comment: Harperking will need to individually add each worksheet as a reference. if he's going to do that, might as well copy-and-paste.